# Trouble with NPM package

Tags: javascript, npm

I have an npm package at https://github.com/thwee-alchemist/FourDSocketProxy, and was wondering if you could help me figure out why

```
require('./FourDSocketProxyServer.js')
```

works, but

```
require('fourdoscketproxy')
```

-- the name of the package on npm -- doesn't. Github has the latest version of my code, and so does npm.

I tested the package on my local machine, and it works, then I followed the publish and version instructions, but for some reason the HTML in fourdsocketproxy throws errors, whereas the former does not.

Comment: did you try require('fourdsocketproxy').fourd as explained on Github?

Comment: I changed the github README right after submitting this post.

Comment: ahhh im with you

Comment: Would you let me know if the new instructions work for you?